# Changing mouse pointer on load of page to a specific div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is is possible to change the mouse pointer(x,y) to some (x2,y2) location when a page is loaded? I want to move my mouse pointer on a particular div, when the page is loaded.

Comment: have you tried anything??

Comment: You can animate that particular DIV on Page load instead of moving mouse pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following fiddle, see if you can find something useful

```
fidde
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkytt/9uczV/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("div-id").mouseover(function(){

    $("div-id").css("cursor","pointer");
});
```